# Help needed creating PDF in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine 1.2.3 in my application and I am trying to create a PDF report based on the following tutorial http://devzone.zend.com/article/12492-Creating-PDF-Documents-with-Zend-Framework using the zend_pdf_table component.

EDIT The document is created but I can only get the first record to appear on the report and still getting the style error despite trying to add my own style.

I may leave this as I am running out of time on the project, I'll look at creating my own PDF from scratch.

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\\WebDocs\\xx\\library\\Zend\\Pdf\\Style.php on line 211
```

My revised code is below

```
// report to print todays appointments
   public function todaysgroomingappointmentsAction()
   {
    try{

    $t=date('y-m-d');

  $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('CONCAT(g.gapmtSTime, g.gapmtETime) AS Time, CONCAT(c.firstname, c.lastname) AS Client, p.name AS Pet, r.groomprocedure AS Procedure, u.name AS Groomer')
    ->from('PetManager_Model_Groomappointments g')
    ->leftJoin('g.PetManager_Model_Clients c')
    ->leftJoin('g.PetManager_Model_Pets p')
    ->leftJoin('g.PetManager_Model_Users u')
    ->leftJoin('g.PetManager_Model_Groomservices s')
    ->leftJoin('s.PetManager_Model_Groomprocedures r')
    ->where('g.gapmtStatus = 1 AND g.gapmtDate = ?',$t);
    $result = $q->fetchArray();

  require_once 'Zend/Pdf.php';;         
  require_once 'My/Pdf.php';    
  require_once 'My/Pdf/Document.php';
  require_once 'My/Pdf/Page.php';
  require_once 'My/Pdf/Table.php';
  require_once 'My/Pdf/Table/Row.php';
  require_once 'My/Pdf/Table/Cell.php';
  require_once 'My/Pdf/Table/Column.php';
  require_once 'My/Pdf/Table/HeaderRow.php';  

    // create PDF
    $pdf = new My_Pdf_Document('todaysappointments.pdf', 'D:/');

    // create page
    $page = $pdf->createPage();

    // define font resource
   $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);

   // set font
  $page->setFont($font, 24);

  // create table
 $table = new My_Pdf_Table(4);

 // iterate over record set
 // set up table content
  foreach ($result as $record) {
   $row = new My_Pdf_Table_Row();
  $cols = array();
  foreach ($record as $k => $v) {
   $col = new My_Pdf_Table_Column();
    $col->setText($v);
    $cols[] = $col;      
  }
  $row->setColumns($cols);
  $row->setFont($font, 14);
  $row->setBorder(My_Pdf::TOP, new Zend_Pdf_Style());
  $row->setBorder(My_Pdf::BOTTOM, new Zend_Pdf_Style());
  $row->setBorder(My_Pdf::LEFT, new Zend_Pdf_Style());
  $row->setCellPaddings(array(10,10,10,10));
  $table->addRow($row);
 }

  // add table to page
 $page->addTable($table, 0, 0);

 // add page to document
 $pdf->addPage($page);

 // save as file
 $pdf->save('todaysappointments.pdf');
  echo 'SUCCESS: Document saved!';  
  } catch (Zend_Pdf_Exception $e) {
  die ('PDF error: ' . $e->getMessage());  
 } catch (Exception $e) {
 die ('Application error: ' . $e->getMessage());    
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me why I'getting this error and how I can fix it.

Many thanks.

Comment: `Zend_Pdf_Style` line #211 is `return $this->_lineWidth->value;` so I guess it's a problem with the `$_lineWidth` property

Comment: Just a side note: A little [autloading](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html) here would help to tighten this up a bit.

Comment: @Phil the lineWidth is actually provided by the package itself I've tried to enter it in my code but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save then you must add a filename as argument to $pdf->save(), if you need just print out the content you can use echo $pdf->render(), of course with sending right headers for pdf.

About styles, you must define any style using Zend_Pdf_Style, not just pass empty new Zend_Pdf_Style(), something like:

$style = new Zend_Pdf_Style();
$style->setLineColor( new Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb( 0, 0, 0 ) );
$style->setLineWidth( 1 );

Comment: The package actually allows you to specify the document and directory to save the file to and I can now open it as I didn't place the try block correctly. Dumb I know, however I can't get more than one record to appear on in the generated document and I'm still getting the style error. I did add the document name to the save argument.

Comment: You must to define at least `$_lineWidth` in `Zend_Pdf_Style`. I checked it inside that class and defaultly the variable is  set `null`, but the row you are creating is trying to call method `getLineWidth()` on style class, inside this method exists line `return $this->_lineWidth->value;`, finally it tries to read `value` from `null`. Try to instantiate `Zend_Pdf_Style` and call on it `setLineWidth()` propably even with 0, it will help.

Comment: @ Arek Jablonski I instantiated Zend_Pdf_Style under the variable name myStyle and added the lines as you suggested in your answer however I'm still receiving the error relating to line 211 of the base zend class, and only one of the records is being printed in the document. Thanks for your help I'm thinking of moving on due to the deadline and that I'm having an issue exporting to MS-Excel as well that I'm looking at/for help with at the moment on here.